# toBe() failing in string comparision

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I was working in a test and I have and expect block like `expect(getHighChartDataLabel(container).textContent.trim()).toBe('AFN 4.97M')` and the test is failing, even I'm getting the same value.

Can anyone help me where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can be sure they aren't the same value, most likely because of whitespace character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say based off a screenshot, but as a means of figuring out how they differ - I would guess one contains a nonprintable character, or a character which looks identical but is in fact a different - e.g.

```js
console.log('A' === 'Α') // 'A' === "\u0391"

let str = 'a\x08bc';
console.log(str);
console.log('abc');
console.log(str === 'abc');
```

I would try comparing their lengths, and then compare character by character:

```
const text = getHighchartDataLabel(container).textContent.trim();
const expected = 'AFN 4.97M';
expect(text.length).toBe(expected.length);
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    expect(text[i]).toBe(expected[i]);
}
```

Comment: It was the issue with space. I compared the ascii code and it was 160 and 32 that's why this was failing. Thanks @dave